# How to sort a list of people by birth and death dates when data are incomplete

Tags: mysql, sorting, date

I have a list of people who may or may not have a birth date and/or a death date. I want to be able to sort them meaningfully - a subjective term - by birth date.

BUT - if they don't have a birth date but they to have a death date, I want to have them collated into the list proximal to other people who died then.

I recognize that this is not a discrete operation - there is ambiguity about where someone should go when their birth date is missing. But I'm looking for something that is a good approximation, most of the time.

Here's an example list of what I'd like:

```
Alice     1800     1830
Bob       1805     1845
Carol              1847
Don       1820     1846
Esther    1825     1860
```

In this example, I'd be happy with Carol appearing either before or after Don - that's the ambiguity I'm prepared to accept. The important outcome is that Carol is sorted in the list relative to her death date as a death date, not sorting the death dates in with the birth dates.

What doesn't work is if I coalesce or otherwise map birth and death dates together. For example, `ORDER BY birth_date, death_date` would put Carol after Esther, which is way out of place by my thinking.

Comment: Alice was born in 1802

Comment: Thinking about this more, I find another way to say what I want is to sort by death date and then, for just the people with non-null birth dates, do a stable sort to correct the birth date order - and keep the people with null birth dates where they are. Does that help clarify what I'm trying to do in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to calculate an average age people end up living (for those having both birth and death dates). And either subtract them from death date or add them to birth date for people who don't have the other one.

Doing this in one query may not be efficient, and perhaps ugly because mysql doesn't have windowing functions. You may be better of precalculating the average living age beforehand. But let's try to do it in one query anyway:

```
SELECT   name, birth_date, death_date
FROM     people
ORDER BY COALESCE(
    birth_date,
    DATE_SUB(death_date, INTERVAL (
        SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(death_date, birth_date))
        FROM people 
        WHERE birth_date IS NOT NULL AND death_date IS NOT NULL
    ) DAY)
)
```

Comment: Yes, that would work approximately, which is pretty good. I agree that the problem is calculating the average age in the query, which will slow it down. I would probably calculate the average age overnight (since it doesn't change dramatically from hour to hour), and use that value all day by reference - instead of calculating it every time.

Answer (score 1):

**N.B.:** I've tried with a larger dataset, and it is not working completely as I'd expect.

Try with this query (it needs an `id` primary key column):

```sql
SELECT * FROM people p
ORDER BY (
    CASE WHEN birth IS NOT NULL THEN (
        SELECT ord FROM (
                SELECT id, @rnum := @rnum + 1 AS ord
                FROM people, (SELECT @rnum := 0) r1
                ORDER BY (CASE WHEN birth IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), birth, death
            ) o1
        WHERE id = p.id
        ) ELSE (
        SELECT ord FROM (
                SELECT id, @rnum := @rnum + 1 AS ord
                FROM people, (SELECT @rnum := 0) r2
                ORDER BY (CASE WHEN death IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), death, birth
            ) o2
        WHERE id = p.id
        )
    END)
;
```

What I've done is, basically, to sort the dataset two times, once by birth date and then by death date. Then I've used these two sorted lists to assign the final order to the original dataset, picking the place from the birth-sorted list at first, and using the place from the death-sorted list when a row has no birth date.

Here's a few problems with that query:

- I didn't run it against lots of datasets, so I can't really guarantee it will work with any dataset;
- I didn't check its performance, so it could be quite slow on large datasets.

This is the table I've used to write it, tested with MySQL 5.6.21 (I can't understand why, but [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is rejecting my scripts with a `Create script error`, so I can't provide you with a live example).

Table creation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `people` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `birth` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `death` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Data (I actually slightly changed yours):

```sql
INSERT INTO `people` (`name`, `birth`, `death`) VALUES ('Alice', 1800, NULL);
INSERT INTO `people` (`name`, `birth`, `death`) VALUES ('Bob', 1805, 1845);
INSERT INTO `people` (`name`, `birth`, `death`) VALUES ('Carol', NULL, 1847);
INSERT INTO `people` (`name`, `birth`, `death`) VALUES ('Don', 1820, 1846);
INSERT INTO `people` (`name`, `birth`, `death`) VALUES ('Esther', 1815, 1860);
```

Comment: Very impressive. I believe that this works sort of the way I want it to. Let me play with it a bit and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @DMac Thank you. However, I saw that the more the gaps (i.e. NULL values) in the data, the more the two orderings move away, so probably that `ord` value has to be fixed by a correction factor somehow.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a subquery to pick a suitable birthdate for sorting purposes 
and then a union to join with the records with a birthdate 
for example:

```
select d1.name, null as birthdate, d1.deathdate, max(d2.birthdate) sort from
d as d1, d as d2
where d1.birthdate is null and d2.deathdate <=d1.deathdate
group by d1.name, d1.deathdate

union all

select name, birthdate, deathdate, birthdate from d
where birthdate is not null

order by 4
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d91c/1

Comment: I don't know if it is me or not, but I can't see your sqlfiddle example.

Comment: @DMac And I can't see yours.

Comment: @Strawberry - what do you mean? I didn't make or refer to a sqlfiddle example.

Comment: @DMac Luckily, it's never too late

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will work, but worth a try (I can't test this on MySQL) so trying to guess:

```
order by case birth_date when null then death_date else birth_date end case
```

Comment: For people who have no death date, that would put their rows next to people born when they died. In my example, that would put Carol after Esther.

Comment: Hm... yes it would, this actually just uses a different column to sort on if the primary column is null, so that's not it. Tricky!

Comment: Yes, you're now understanding the nature of the question - tricky indeed!